# A frequently uttered sentence, phrase, or question

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that captures the idea of a frequently uttered sentence, phrase, or question.

For instance, there is one sentence or phrase which can be uttered most often during communication:

> **Henry:** Your best friend has stolen my pen.
>
> **John:**  - What is his name? James? James is honest; he wouldn't steal anyone's pen.

John asked "What's his name?" even when he knows that his best friend's name is James.

For another example, suppose John meets his best friend, James, and asked James whether he had stolen the pen:

> **John:** James, did you steel Henry's pen? He blamed you.
>
> **James:** No, I didn't steal it. But I did see my younger brother, Jacob,  steal that pen.
>
> **John:** What's his name? Harry? Perhaps he stole it.

I have two examples of such repeatedly uttered sentences/arguments in my native language (with translation):

> 1. Mind na kariye ga. **[translation: don't mind]**
> 2. Allah apko neki de. **[translation: may Allah guide you]**

---

Note that the word **[earworm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/earworm)** is not what I am looking for. Earworm means:

> A catchy song or tune that runs continually through a person's mind.

Thus it is wrong to use such word in this case.

Comment: +1 However, it's not "earworm," so why even mention it? That's actually a digression.

Comment: @Kris, I mentioned to clear the air in my mind.

Comment: Can you give a sentence in which this word/phrase should appear? It's. It clear what you're looking for. Is it something like cliche, idiom, figure, trope, pattern?

Comment: @Mitch, perhaps **cliche**, but I don't know its connotation?

Comment: @Iqbal you may not know the connotation of 'cliche' but you haven't given enough connotation of what you want for us to know either. You need to explain more the situation, give more examples.

Comment: @Mitch, I have now edited my question. Have a read.

Comment: If it's characteristic of an individual, I would suggest "trademark" or "catch phrase".

Comment: "Common phrase"

Comment: Which is to say I think there is a lot of nuance for what you want that you haven't yet said. Do you have a term for this in your native language? Do you have any more examples? ("What's his name?" Is not common). Do you mean a ... there's just to many possibilities. Why do you start off with 'ear worm' when that's what you don't want at all? Start your question from scratch.

Comment: @Mitch, I have some examples in my native language, too... I will try to explain them in the body of question with translation.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a word for it in your native language? That would help a lot.

Comment: @Mitch, I don't have any word. Perhaps, there may be no such word in my native language.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal, I've added definitions for perissology and pleonasm to my answer. Perhaps those are the words you're looking for :)

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal I edited your question extensively to make it more idiomatic English. There are _many, many_ words in English that could work for you, because the only real thing that I can gather from your words is that you want a word phrase for "a common phrase". If What you are looking for is moe specific than this, then you should add more description.

Comment: @Mitch, thanks for the edit..../ I think, **moe** is a Japanese word?

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal haha. No, 'moe' is a typo for  'more'. But it is too late for me to fix.

Comment: And just so you know, the current answers all have very particular nuances which may or may not fit what you want. Until you get those figured out, I would not recommend using any of the suggestions.

Comment: Also, you really need to give a sentence in which you expect to use the term anyone suggests. That way we can provide an adjective, noun, generic term, etc which ver one will fit, and avoid those that don't fit. Edit you question to give a template sentence for how you expect to use it. That is, a sentence with a blank to insert the word/phrase.

Comment: @Mitch, suggestions in answers did not fit my need. But, I am going for the **catchy phrase**.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be thinking of "a refrain"?

It's *generally used in music*, e.g. when the chorus is repeated. Though [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/refrain) gives

> A repeated utterance or theme.

and

> a much repeated saying or idea

as *secondary definitions*

[Richard Le Gallienne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Le_Gallienne) used the word, to mean repetition of an utterance, in chapter VII of his book [The Quest of The Golden Girl](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/461/461-h/461-h.htm#chap0107)

> Dinner!
>
> Is there a more beautiful word in the language?
>
> Dinner!
>
> Let the beautiful word come as **a refrain** to and fro this chapter.
>
> Dinner!
>
> Just eating and drinking, nothing more, but so much!

On doing further research, searching the term [often repeated utterance](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/often-repeated-utterance), I found [mantra](https://www.google.pt/search?q=define%20mantra&oq=define%20mantra&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.3932j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as a possibility.

> a statement or slogan repeated frequently.
>
> "the environmental mantra that energy has for too long been too cheap"

or maybe you are just looking for [tics](https://www.publicationcoach.com/verbal-tics/)?

> an idiosyncratic and habitual feature of a person's behaviour.
>
> "they've developed a verbal tic which involves repeating odd bits of each other's utterances"

or [perissology and pleonasm](https://thesaurus.plus/related/perissology/pleonasm) ?

> perissology (noun rhetoric)
>
> the use of a superfluity of words; an expression of something using more words than necessary

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pleonasm)

> pleonasm (noun rhetoric)
>
> 1. the use of more words than necessary or an instance of this, such as a tiny little child
> 2. a word or phrase that is superfluous

Comment: I think, refrain has to do with the poems, not common sentence or arguments. **Refrain** denotes a repeated line or number
of lines in a poem or song,
typically at the end of each
verse.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal Yes, I agree. The source I quoted (TFD) gave the alternative definitions as #2 and #3 choices. I've just found a reference for refrain where it's used in the context of repeating a word. I'll edit my answer to add it.

Comment: @Iqbal That's a common refrain about word requests, that people ignore secondary definitions.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal - "That old refrain" is often used to describe a phrase that someone often (boringly) repeats.  I can easily think of a half-dozen political catch phrases that this would apply to.

Comment: @HotLicks, I think, that's case you are referring to: **boringle repeats**.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal - That's "boringly", the adverbial form of "boring".

Comment: @HotLicks, Sorry, I mistakenly typed that.

Comment: 'Pleonasm' just got written down - I'll be using that literally every single day that ends in a 'y' - including weekdays. Thank you.

Comment: @Inoutguttiwutts :D

Comment: 'pleonasm' describes something that is redundant _within itself_. That is, in one instance, there is repetition _of meaning_. The OP is looking for a word/phrase for a word/phrase that is used frequently. And 'perissology' would not be used to say " The phrase 'What's his name?' is a perissology." (that's the usage the OP is looking for.

Comment: @HotLicks 'catch phrase' fits what the OP describes, but is probably not what they want.

Comment: @Mitch, **perissology** denotes a kind of verbosity; the word I want doesn't necessarily has to do with it. Any word or phrase that denotes a habit of uttering the same phrase or sentence most often will be welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Pet phrase**

[Not the best source, but confirms usage I have heard:](https://www.thoughtco.com/pet-phrase-1691501)

> Pet phrase is an informal term for an expression frequently used by an individual in speech and/or writing.
>
> A pet phrase may be widely known (a cliché, for instance) or peculiar to the individual who employs it.

I can't think of anything else that Bookmanu hasn't already added.

Answer (score 1):

If the phrase is somewhat habitual, consider calling it a verbal tic.

> 1.1 An idiosyncratic and habitual feature of a person's behaviour.
>   ‘they've developed a verbal tic which involves repeating odd bits of each other's utterances’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tic)